# MySQL Partitioning a table with an auto incrementing BIGINT unique primary key

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a hypothetical table with a primary key that is a BIGINT. Let's say my table grows very large and I have to partition and create different partitions by date range. What happens with primary key? Does that mean I can exceed the capacity of the BIGINT since there are more tables now? How does MySQL keep from assigning duplicate primary keys assuming a BIGINT set to auto increment a unique value?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitioning doesn't create a new table. There is still one table with many partitions. Auto increment unique value keeps it functionality. Data grouped in partitions by date field that you choose to create partitions with.

Take a look at this : http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_55_partitioning.html

Comment: Note that you would have to change the primary key to include the date column to be able to partition that table. e.g. PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at).